# Unable to change the volume. When I press the volume keys in MAC OS X and above

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I can change the volume in the application but the problem is when I try to change volume in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me. Open terminal

```
  sudo killall coreaudiod
```